# unable to change ip address because ipconfig is telling me the ethernet cable is disconnected when its not

Tags: ethernet

lenovo something running windows 8
This is what I get:
"No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection while it has it's media disconnected."

The ethernet cable is connected and internet is working fine.

Comment: Do you have multiple ethernet connections on the computer? (Some motherboards do)

Comment: Actually I only have one but ipconfig shows 2. Also when I click the network icon it always shows an extra nonexistent ethernet connection. It's been like that for a while and I don't think it was there when I first bought the computer.

Comment: Additional, virtual network adapters will be installed for VPN or Virtualization software.